# android google maps markers, info windows

Tags: android, google-maps, infowindow, markers

Hi is there any possible way to make the information windows visible on a marker  without having to click on the marker ??If so how is this possible ? Many thanks.

```
     map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.rest))
    .position(restt1)
     .title("r1 Restaurant")
                 .snippet("RESTAURANT")
```

The above code it opens the info window when the marker is clicked, but I want the info window to be displayed constantly without having to click on the marker.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference to the marker all you have to do is call `showInfoWindow()`

```
marker.showInfoWindow();
```

Comment: thank you it worked, I will accept you question in 10 minutes :). Is there any way to do the same thing lets say on mouse over ?

Comment: I think you should take a loot at the API reference to see what you can and cant do https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/package-summary.html